# Having trouble understanding a struct in C

Tags: c, struct

I'm working on a networking project and I came across this struct in the skeleton code I'm working with:

```
struct sr_icmp_hdr {
   uint8_t icmp_type;
   uint8_t icmp_code;
   uint16_t icmp_sum;
} __attribute__ ((packed)) ;
typedef struct sr_icmp_hdr sr_icmp_hdr_t;
```

Can someone explain what the code following the struct is? What is `__attribute__` or a `typedef`?

I'm used to seeing this in C++:

```
struct hi{
    int thisIsAnInt;
    double thisIsADouble;
}
```

and declaring a struct like this:

```
hi hello;
cout << hello.thisIsAnInt;
```

Is this different in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C++, when you define or declare a class or struct, the tag name is automatically available for use as a type name.

In C, this does not happen, so to get the same effect as in C++, you have to add:

```
typedef struct xxx xxx;
```

Some people prefer to keep the structure tags separate from the type names, though they're in separate namespaces and it isn't necessary.  I almost always use the same name for the tag and the type name to emphasize that they're referring to the same type.

Hence:

```
struct sr_icmp_hdr {
   uint8_t icmp_type;
   uint8_t icmp_code;
   uint16_t icmp_sum;
} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

This defines `struct sr_icmp_hdr`; the attribute is noise.  The attribute is not a standardized part of C, but is implemented in GCC.  It ensures that there are no padding bytes within the structure, though the layout is such that only a perverse compiler would add padding bytes in the first place.  Hence my characterization of it as 'noise'.  (I've been coding in C for quite a while and not had cause to use it.  Clearly, other people have different experiences or it wouldn't be in the compiler.)

```
typedef struct sr_icmp_hdr sr_icmp_hdr_t;
```

This defines a type name `sr_icmp_hdr_t` that is an alias for `struct sr_icmp_hdr`.  More generally, `typedef` introduces an alternative name for a type.  For example, `uint8_t` is a `typedef` defined in `<stdint.h>` in C; likewise `uint16_t`.  Such names are used to promote portability, in general.

Note that C++ permits `typedef struct xxx xxx;` even though it is not necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't call the attribute "noise"; it's a gcc-specific extension (though in this particular case it probably has no effect).

Comment: I was editing the attribute commentary as you commented.  I think it is noise, but I've given a more complete characterization of what it does and why I think it is noise.

Answer (score 1):

1) attribute **packed** is a GCC specific declaration (not part of C standard). It is described here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

This particular attribute is a hint for the compiler to use as little memory as possible to store the objects of the described struct.

2) Unlike C++, in C, without that typedef you would have to declare the objects of the given struct as:

`struct sr_icmp_hdr mystruct;`

Answer (score 0):

For the last part of your question, C does not have overloaded operators for output, but you could go:

```
hi hello = { 2, 1. };
printf("%d\n", hello.thisIsAnInt);
```